# Div can not be scrolled only the browser window has scrollbars

Tags: css, html, scroll

The left and the right side has much text but can not be scrolled independendly from each other because I have to scroll the whole browser window.

How can I scroll text longer than the vertical screen in the left and right div without having a browser window scrollbar?

http://jsfiddle.net/uFDK5/5/

CSS:

```
body {
     background-color:Yellow;   
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:100%; 
    width:100%;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

#DataGridButtonBar
{
    background-color:Fuchsia;     
}

#TreeButtonBar
{     
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:Maroon;    
}

#TreeWrapper{
   background-color:Aqua;    
   width:200px; 
   float:left;      
}

#DataGridWrapper{
     background-color:Silver; 
}

.clear
{
    clear:both;    
}

input button
{
    display:inline;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="TreeButtonBar">

    <input type="button" value="Add Node" />
    <input type="button" value="Delete Node" />

</div>    

<div id="DataGridButtonBar">      
    <input type="button" value="Add row" />
    <input type="button" value="Delete row" />
</div>    

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="TreeWrapper">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>


<div id="DataGridWrapper">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#TreeWrapper{
    background-color: aqua;    
    width: 200px; 
    float: left;      
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#DataGridWrapper{
    background-color: silver;
    position: fixed;
    left: 200px;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: when there is less text there is always a scrollbar visible? I do not want that. http://jsfiddle.net/uFDK5/9/

Comment: @Pascal simple, just change overflow-y: scroll; to overflow-y: auto; I've made that change in the code above for you.

Answer (score 1):

This works, however you might want to fiddle width the height and widths...

```
body {
     background-color:Yellow;   
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

#DataGridButtonBar
{
    background-color:Fuchsia;     
}

#TreeButtonBar
{     
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:Maroon;

}

#TreeWrapper{
   background-color:Aqua;    
   width:200px;
   height:400px;
   float:left;
   overflow:scroll;    
}

#DataGridWrapper{
     background-color:Silver;
     width:300px;
     height:400px;
     float:left;
     overflow:scroll;
}

.clear
{
    clear:both;    
}

input button
{
    display:inline;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the overflow property in css.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score 0):

You use the `overflow: scroll;` CSS property on both you div-elements to accomplish that. So in you case it would be:

```
#TreeWrapper, #DataGridWrapper {
   overflow: scroll; 
}
```